# What does offsetStackFrame do in JVM Specification

Tags: java, jvm

What does  `offsetStackFrame` Prolog predicate do in JVM Spec?

Although I'm not a Prolog expert I could get a grasp of all the other predicates in Prolog in this Spec but I can't understand this one.

Here is the definition of this predicate in JVM Spec on page 174:

```
offsetStackFrame(Environment, Offset, StackFrame) :-
 allInstructions(Environment, Instructions),
 member(stackMap(Offset, StackFrame), Instructions).
```

On page 178 `instruction` is defined as:

```
instruction(Offset, AnInstruction)
```

And here is the definition of `stackMap` on page 180:

```
stackMap(Offset, TypeState)
```

Also `TypeState` is defined as below:

```
frame(Locals, OperandStack, Flags)
```

I can't understand what does `member(stackMap(Offset, StackFrame), Instructions)` do in the definition of `offsetStackFrame`. I consider `Instructions` as `[instruction(offset, AnInstruction)]` and `stackMap(Offset, TypeState)` as `[(Offset, frame(Locals, OperandStack, Flags))]`. So what is the purpose of this predicate?

Comment: “*Although I'm not a Prolog expert*”… I suppose, no one of the JVM spec’s target audience is.

Answer (score 1):

I'll come back and improve this answer later. If I don't please comment to send me a notification as I don't have much time right now. I have run the prolog in the spec so I should be able to provide a IRL example.

Basically to aid the verification process classfiles contain the type state of the operand stack/locals at certain key bytecode offsets(typically after branches where control flow merges). These type states are called stackmap frames. The prolog code has a predicate which combines the known stackmap frames and instructions(called `mergeStackMapFrames` or something). Then it iterates over the merged result to verify that all the state transitions are valid/match the instruction in question.

How the predicate above fits into that is that it asserts that a particular stackmap frame is present in the merged instruction/stackmap frames.
Due to the nature of prolog you can use this assertion to construct the merged list in the first place.

Comment: I got it, that was great but please make it more clear for others by referring to associated part in the JVM Spec.